# How to track https urls through Android emulator using Fiddler?

Tags: android, emulation, fiddler, flurry

I want to use Flurry in my android app, I have created an account, got api and using that api and I can use onEvent methods in FlurryAgent.

Now I want to track those calls in fiddler to check, I am able to trace the http calls, but https calls are getting failed.

I did the following,

Changed the SSL settings in Fiddler and Firefox, so if I open any https urls in Firefox browser then it's tracked, but I am not able to track the calls through Android emulator.

I have changed the emulator settings like given in this link http://aurir.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/tutorial-getting-android-emulator-working-with-fiddler-http-proxy-tool/
even though it is not working.

Comment: My understanding is that the Android emulator team regressed their proxy support and thus no longer works with Fiddler. You should contact the Google team for help on that.

Answer (score -2):

you can always use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) instead of fiddler.

it easy to use and you dont need any special settings

Comment: I believe he's going to have problems reading the encrypted HTTPS traffic with Wireshark.